# How to SUM on all column based on their own key?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

As the title, I am stuck with getting the SUM of category A and B ( as shown in the pic below )

[image]

The left side is the **Total** and the right side is **Individual**.
All I want is to get the total value of **120 for category A** and **150 for category B**.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A3:

```
=SUMIF(D3:J4,"A",E3:K4)
```

B3:

```
=SUMIF(D3:J4,B2,E3:K4)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**A3:**    `=SUM(E3+G3+I3+K3)` or simply: `=E3+G3+I3+K3` or `=SUM(E3:K3)`
**B3:**    `=SUM(E4+G4+I4+K4)` or simply: `=E4+G4+I4+K4` or `=SUM(E4:K4)`